# Passing data from javascript to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

All action is in VIEW.

How my app looks now: I get JSON data from websocket server and have it in some JS variable.

I want to create in my View dynamic table of content of this data. My idea is pass data somehow (?) from js to asp.net View and using for loop to create table of this data.

Should I try using ajax? and how to pass this data?

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes kindly provide some code or some link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MsCh1A0e
 this is JS script which one get json data by websocket, ii could pass this data (variabe 'b') to div by id, but i dont want to send every single json data like b.name[0].Value =$('name0'),  b.name[1].Value =$('name1')
and i dont know how do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create a table view from the json data which you received, you can use DataTables plugin which is a very popular jQuery Javascript library and highly flexible tool and you will get many addtional feature like sorting, filtering easily.

Here is a sample which you can follow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/jsonp.php",
            "dataType": "jsonp"
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

You will get many more useful examples from the origin site: [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp.html)

Moreover, you also can do this in many other ways if you use a javascript framework like AngularJS or KnockoutJS.